# How to add array on array if id same on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array like this

```
const myArr = [
 {
   uuid: 123,
   name: aa
 },
 {
   uuid: 456,
   name: bbb
 }
]
```

How to add a new array if I call API with UUID above this

example: domain.com/product-option/456

I want this response :

```
const myArr = [
 {
   uuid: 123,
   name: aa
 },
 {
   uuid: 456,
   name: bbb,
   product-option : [
     {
       uuid:01,
       name: abcd
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: you need to explain little bit more - exactly what do you want?

Comment: after calling an api you want to add new `product-option` array to existing array with `uuid: 456` ?

Comment: or you need help in API side?

Comment: yes sir, after calling an api you want to add new product-option array to existing array with uuid: 456 @SagarDarekar

Comment: `product-option` uuid is different from `uuid: 456`, how do you link them? @AgusyogiSumanjaya

Comment: so the case is like this, I have a dynamic select input field, to fill in the options I have to get api data from the uuid input select above @NickVu

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when you call an `api` with any `uuid` you want to add returned response to that particular item in array.
So lets say you have called `api` with `uuid:456` so you want to include `api` response into existing array with `uuid:456`

```
domain.com/product-option/456
```

To do that after you get successful `api` response you can add new property `product-option` to your existing array `myArr` using following code -

```
myArr.forEach((element) => {
  if(element.uuid === uuid){
    element['product-option'] = response.data;
  }
});
```

Comment: If you use [myArr.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/some) you could add `product-option` and return true to stop. This prevents looping all elements.